# Отмена map.setArea()

Tags: yandex-maps-api, drupal, yandex-maps-jsapi

Есть код

```
myPlacemark.events
      .add('click',function(e){
         myMap.margin.addArea({top: 0, right: 0, width: '500px', height: '100%'});
        var pm = e.get('target');
          myMap.panTo(pm.geometry.getCoordinates(), {
          delay: 0,
          useMapMargin: true
          }); 
        if($(window).width() < 992) {
          myPlacemark.options.set('balloonAutoPan', true);
          myMap.margin.destroy();
        }
       });
```

При первом клике код срабатывает правильно-добавляется область. При последующих кликах область пропадает,в консоль выводит [0,0,0,0]. Но если закрывать балун и кликать на метку,то все работает хорошо
РЕШЕНИЕ:

```
myPlacemark.events
      .add('click', function(e){
        if (activePlacemark) {

          myMap.balloon.close();
        }
        activePlacemark = e.get('target');
        //код
      });
```

Comment: Соберите пример воспроизводящий проблему. Код который вы предоставили проблему не демонстрирует jsfiddle.net/sx1omfge/9

Comment: Решил задачу. Возник другой вопрос,как отменить setArea при разрешении меньше 992px? метод myMap.margin.destroy() не помогает

Comment: так ? http://jsfiddle.net/c3jktq2g/

Comment: Да! Большое спасибо. Только изменил отступы под свои нужны. Я пытался  задавать myMap.margin.addArea({top: 0, right: 0, width: 0, height: '100%'}); но так не убирался